# What’s right way to access parent property inside of ‘templated child element’

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mvvm

I've created template, and template element traverse up to not a logical hierarchy but physical hierarchy such as direct window, direct view.
Why is that? What’s right way to access parent property inside of ‘templated child element’?

-- View model code

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    if (IsInDesignMode)
    {
        Cars = new List<string>() { "Audi", "BMW", "Ferrari", "Ford" };
        Models = new List<string>() { "Model 1", "Model 2" };
    }
    else
    {
        Cars = new List<string>() { "Audi", "BMW", "Ferrari", "Ford" };
        Models = new List<string>() { "Model 1", "Model 2" };
    }
}

public List<string> Models { get; private set; }

public List<string> Cars { get; private set; }
```

Item template selector

```
public class ComboBoxTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate
        SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var element = container as FrameworkElement;

        var dataTemplate = element.FindResource(((item is string) && item.Equals("Ferrari")) ?
                                                       "DataTemplateTopLevelCombobox2" : "DataTemplateTopLevelCombobox1") as DataTemplate;

        return dataTemplate;
    }
}
```

-- Main application xaml code

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:proj="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" DataContext="{Binding Main, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsPanelTemplateHorizontal">
            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <proj:QualityComboBoxTemplateSelector x:Key="QualityComboBoxTemplateSelector"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="87.2,44.8,0,0" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}" 
                  ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource ItemsPanelTemplateHorizontal}"
                  ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ComboBoxTemplateSelector}"
                  x:Name="CarsComboBox"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Resource dictionary

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateTopLevelCombobox1">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" >
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateTopLevelCombobox2">
    <Border Width="100" >
        <ComboBox Text="Custom" Height="21.96"
        ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Models??"/>
    </Border>       
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Actually my question is about data binding `ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Models??"/>`, for this binding I've tried different approached like `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Models, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"` OR `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.RecordingResolutions, RelativeSource={RelativeSource {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}}"`. But nothing worked. It would be helpful if you could guide me in setting data context for this.

Comment: My issue is solved after overriding data context for Border as below `<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateTopLevelCombobox2">
    <Border Width="100" DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}">
        <ComboBox Text="Custom" Height="21.96"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Models}"/>
    </Border>       
</DataTemplate>`

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you implemented FindResource is correct as FindeResource traverse up in tree and Searches for a resource with the specified key. [FindResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> But If you already know that your ResourceDictionary is Merged to App resources then you can access it directly like

```
App.Current.Resources["DataTemplateTopLevelCombobox2"]
```

This will fail in case your ResourceDictionary is merged to Window Resources but FindResource won't.